# Do optimization like this make sense?

Tags: c, optimization

You have two arrays and a function that counts differences between them:

```
for( i = 0; i < len; ++i ) { 
    int value1 = vector1[i];
    int value2 = vector2[i];
    if( value1 != value2 ) ++num_differences;
}
```

As branching downgrades performance, it can be optimized to:

```
for( i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
    num_differences += !!(vector1[i] != vector2[i])
}
// !!(..) is to be sure that the result is boolean 0 or 1
```

so there is no `if` clause. But does it practically make sense? With GCC (and other compilers) being so smart, does it make sense to play with such optimizations?

Comment: why do you need !!, with a !=? triple negative. mind blown.

Comment: Have you tried measuring it? Current x86-64 processors have conditional move instructions, so no branching is needed in your first example. (assuming the compiler is smart enough to generate them)

Comment: @KshitijMehta is right. The result of the `!=` is guaranteed to be `0` or `1`.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is: "Trust your Compiler".

In general you're not going to see much benefit from optimisations like this unless you're working with really huge datasets.  Even then you really need to benchmark the code to see if there is any improvement.

Comment: Hooray for letting the machines do micro-optimization so you can spend your time finding a better way to solve the larger problem

Comment: Most of times there won't be any difference at all on final binary. Machine optimizes, that's the way it is and that's the way it should be

Comment: The compiler is only as good as the source code you feed it. Learn how to help the compiler do a better job and you will automatically become a better programmer.

Comment: @tbert: the problem is that most programmers solve the larger problem and then leave it. The "better way" doesn't come into play, more likely the "first way."

Comment: @ArcDare: "won't be any difference at all" are you saying that on the basis of your own failed attempts or just passing on something you've heard? My personal experience is exactly the opposite.

Comment: @OlofForshell then probably you write unefficient code that in fact needs to be optimized. I'm talking about compiling two similar codes (one "compressed" - one "human readable") and having generated the same binary. That's what the compiler does with extreme precission. Other issue is you just make it compile innecesary things

Comment: @ArcDare: I will assume that by "compressed" you mean "difficult to understand." The compiler will generate according to what you feed it. It's not alchemy: different source codes produce different machine code. I'm usually aware of what the resulting machine code will be in broader terms. What I can't do automatically is write code that will run efficiently on multiple cores or that makes the best use of cache lines. For that I profile. My experience is that different conclusions may be drawn from every optimization experience. Lots can be done with the OP's code, for example.

Comment: @OlofForshell:  I agree that the compiler doesn't free the programmer from having to know how to write efficient code.  There is a big difference, for example, in the assembly code generated for a recursive vs iterative Factorial algorithm.  There are many other design decisions that have a big impact on the code generated by the compiler, and its efficiency.  I think the issue is really the cost of spending the time on micro-optimisations against the benefit gained.  Unless there's a huge data set involved, or you're devloping a critical real time system, the effort is better spent elsewhere.

Comment: If I spend x amount of time today learning how to write more efficient code then that is something that will benefit all future work I do. My future client y might end up with an app that only requires five servers to run instead of nineteen. Day-to-day costs for keeping the system up and running as well as the likelihood of a hardware failure are greatly reduced. On the downside five servers is a lot less flashy than nineteen, I'll grant you that.

Comment: The trend for many years is that most programmers writing mainstream code think that as long as they write code that works, smart compilers, fast computers and ditto communication links will fix the rest - they don't. It wasn't much better twenty years ago with overloaded server applications and overloaded communication links. Thirty years ago a single mainframe application running on one mainframe @ a few MIPS could service the interactive needs of a major bank or insurance corp. Today, you'd need dozens of multi-core, multi-GIPS servers to to the same. It is so wasteful.

Comment: Are the projects more on time today? Is it easier to find the really difficult bugs today? Is the code more maintainable today? Is the code more reusable today? Is the concept that a programmer can be easily replaced by any other more valid today? Anyone can think inside the box and say that 90% of my peers say this or that so it must be true. That doesn't necessarily make it true, certainly not absolutely true.

Answer (score 2):

Unless `len` is several millions large or you're comparing a lot of arrays, then no. The second version is less readable (not so much to an experienced programmer), so I'd prefer the first variant, unless this is the bottleneck (doubtful).

The following codes are generated, with optimizations:

```
   for( i = 0; i < 4; ++i ) { 
    int value1 = vector1[i];
    int value2 = vector2[i];
    if( value1 != value2 ) ++num_differences;
00401000  mov         ecx,dword ptr [vector1 (40301Ch)] 
00401006  xor         eax,eax 
00401008  cmp         ecx,dword ptr [vector2 (40302Ch)] 
0040100E  je          wmain+15h (401015h) 
00401010  mov         eax,1 
00401015  mov         edx,dword ptr [vector1+4 (403020h)] 
0040101B  cmp         edx,dword ptr [vector2+4 (403030h)] 
00401021  je          wmain+26h (401026h) 
00401023  add         eax,1 
00401026  mov         ecx,dword ptr [vector1+8 (403024h)] 
0040102C  cmp         ecx,dword ptr [vector2+8 (403034h)] 
00401032  je          wmain+37h (401037h) 
00401034  add         eax,1 
00401037  mov         edx,dword ptr [vector1+0Ch (403028h)] 
0040103D  cmp         edx,dword ptr [vector2+0Ch (403038h)] 
00401043  je          wmain+48h (401048h) 
00401045  add         eax,1 
   }

   for( i = 0; i < 4; ++i ) {
    num_differences += !!(vector1[i] != vector2[i]);
00401064  mov         edx,dword ptr [vector1+0Ch (403028h)] 
0040106A  xor         eax,eax 
0040106C  cmp         edx,dword ptr [vector2+0Ch (403038h)] 
00401072  mov         edx,dword ptr [vector1+8 (403024h)] 
00401078  setne       al   
0040107B  xor         ecx,ecx 
0040107D  cmp         edx,dword ptr [vector2+8 (403034h)] 
00401083  mov         edx,dword ptr [vector1+4 (403020h)] 
00401089  setne       cl   
0040108C  add         eax,ecx 
0040108E  xor         ecx,ecx 
00401090  cmp         edx,dword ptr [vector2+4 (403030h)] 
00401096  mov         edx,dword ptr [vector1 (40301Ch)] 
0040109C  setne       cl   
0040109F  add         eax,ecx 
004010A1  xor         ecx,ecx 
004010A3  cmp         edx,dword ptr [vector2 (40302Ch)] 
004010A9  setne       cl   
004010AC  add         eax,ecx 
   }
```

So, actually, the second version is slightly slower (theoretically). 19 instructions for the second vs. 17 for the first.

Comment: There's more to it than just counting instructions. The first one has branching and the second doesn't. If anything, I'd guess that the first version is actually slower.

Comment: @Mysticial I know, there's also micro-instructions to be aware of. But I think it's good enough for a *very* rough estimate. But you're the performance expert, why don't you give a thorough answer? :)

Comment: Meh... Too lazy to knock up a benchmark. It's 2:30 AM here - should probably get some sleep.

Comment: @Mysticial is probably right, though it depends a lot on the data. Random data would (strangely) yield an excellent prediction rate (the values would almost never be equal), so the branch version would be fast. But for random 0/1 values, prediction rate would be poor, and branches will cost much more. And all that, assuming the compiler indeed implements `if` as a branch.

Answer (score 1):

You should compare the code the compiler generates. It may be equivalent.

The compiler's very smart, but a good engineer can certainly improve a program's performance.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you are going to do much better, your second example is hard to read/understand for the average programmer which means two things one hard to understand and maintain, two you may be creeping into dark, less tested/supported, corners of the compiler.  Drive down the road between the lines, dont wander about on the shoulder or in the wrong lane.

Go with this

```
for( i = 0; i < len; ++i ) { 
    int value1 = vector1[i];
    int value2 = vector2[i];
    if( value1 != value2 ) ++num_differences;
}
```

or this

```
for( i = 0; i < len; ++i ) { 
    if( vector1[i] != vector2[i] ) ++num_differences;
}
```

if it really is bothering you and you have properly concluded this is your performance bottleneck then time the difference between them.  From the disassembly shown, and the nature of this platform, it is very difficult to properly time such things and draw the right conclusions.  Too many caches, and other factors that cloud over the results, leading to false conclusions, etc.  and no two x86 implementations have the same performance so if you happen to tune for your computer you are likely detuning it for another model of x86 or even the same make on a different motherboard with different I/O characteristics.

Comment: I guess we are all assuming this is x86, is it x86?